# Navigation bar with some elements in centre, some aligned right. Image needs to be resizable

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a Navigation bar with a logo in the centre of it, and then links aligned at the right.  I also need to be able to resize the logo. It should be easy.

With the following, I can just about get what I need.  I just can't get the logo to be central on the top line.

If I don't use `image-size` and `figure` then the logo is central, but I can't resize it.

I've been going round in circles on this, so grateful for help

[example on plnk here](https://plnkr.co/edit/KSJQHd8XSOBOqIZj?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="container">
    <li id="lnkHome"> <a href="index.html" >
      <img class="image-size" src="https://www.stickpng.com/img/download/5e8ce4a6664eae0004085468/image" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="d">LINK1</li>
    <li>LINK2</li>
    <li>LINK3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

`

```css
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: rgba(39, 168, 223, 1);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#lnkHome {
  width: 5;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.image-size {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

figure {
  width: 100px;
}

.d {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `margin-right:auto` from #lnkHome

Comment: I thought that had worked, but it's actually centering the logo in the space to the left of the right side links. It's more obvious when adding more links to the right. I want the logo to be in the actual centre of the page (horizontally)

Comment: then remove both margin-left and margin-right and add  ` position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);` to your #lnkHome element